# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in 32

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting the following error and I was wondering on how to fix?

This is the second time I got this error I fixed it the first time but for some reason I cant fix it the second time.

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types on line 32
```

Here is line 32.

```
    $Views = $Views + 1;
```

Here is the full code below.

require_once 'db.php';

```
if($_REQUEST && isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']) . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $TTVC = "SELECT views FROM user WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']) . "'";
    $TTV = mysql_query($TTVC);
    $total = mysql_fetch_row($TTV);
    $Views = $total;
    $Views = $Views + 1;
    $sql1 = "UPDATE user SET views='$Views' WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']) . "'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
```

Comment: `$Views` is an array (albeit one with a single element), which is not surprising because that's what `mysql_fetch_row` returns. So you are trying to add an integer to an array.

Comment: `UPDATE user SET views=views + 1 WHERE id = ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the entire array representing the selected row to `$Views`:

```
$Views = $total;
```

Presumably, you wanted to extract the selected `views` from it:

```
$Views = $total[0];
```